# application will only access settings in DLL in Debug -

Tags: c#, dll, settings

I have a console application and a windows form application that reference a DLL. The DLL has settings that are modified when used. At the moment, I have messageboxes to show me the DLL properties as it is called. When I run it in Debug mode, everything works as expected. However, when I execute either one of the apps which call the functions in the DLLs - the DLL's settings return the default value. Can anyone enlighten me on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what we have tags for here on [SO].

Comment: how are the settings persisted ? please some source code...

Answer (score 0):

Settings defend on exe, vshost.exe location, version and etc ...

Read these for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(vs.80).aspx

http://braincrash.wordpress.com/2007/08/22/user-settings-in-c/